# Passar Parametros para Store Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc, stored-procedures

Segue o Código da Função da Busca

```
public List<Pessoa> Buscar(string Nome)
{ 
    using(var db = new MyContext())
    {
        var Result = db.Database.SqlQuery<Pessoa>("EXEC SP_Busca_Cliente @Nome", Nome).ToList();
        return Result.ToList();
    }
}
```

PERGUNTA ---- Já Tentei usar o SqlParameters só que retorna o Erro que não está passando o Parâmetro correto para a Stored Procedure Existe Algum Método para definir este parâmetro para passar ele para a Stored Procedure?

Comment: Hugo poste a sua classe `Pessoa` e poste também a sua StoredProcedure!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe sim, o correto é esta sintaxe (usando seu código como exemplo):

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Pessoa>(
    "SP_Busca_Cliente @Nome", new SqlParameter("@Nome", nome));
```

Não precisa do "Exec" antes do nome da procedure, é só colocar o nome da procedure e a lista de parâmetros.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4874600/4343335).

Comment: Legal, Ele Passou o Parametro só que ainda ele me retorna um Erro -- " +  $exception {"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'WebApplication1.Models.Pessoa'. A member of the type, 'Codigo', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."} System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException" -- Será que é List() ?

Comment: Sem o EXEC, Usando do mesmo Jeito que vc Me Passou.

Comment: Ah, ele tá falando que o resultado da sua stored procedure não bate com a classe `Pessoa`, seu select na stored procedure tem colunas com nomes diferentes da classe pessoa.

Comment: Putz, Verdade, Vlew Agora Funcionou sem erros, agorá é só tratar a View Para Retornar a List, Vlew Mesmo Velho

Comment: De nada, só aceitar minha resposta como a correta.